# Most efficient way of transferring large amounts of data from one column to another?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have two tables, and one has a dependency on the other that I want to remove.
Let's say the tables are **Product** and **Employee**, and there are about **800,000** rows in each table.

The Employee table has a ProductID, in which there is a ProductRefID, which I need to reference in my application. The way this is done is to join in the Product table, and reference the ProductRefID that way.

However, I now want to change this so that ProductRefID is a column on the Employee table, and then transfer every Product row's "ProductRefID" to the Employee row's "ProductRefID".

**What would be the most efficient way of writing this query?**

(I know it sounds stupid, but it's just an example, it's not actually what I'm trying to do specifically).

Comment: "I know it sounds stupid, but it's just an example, it's not actually what I'm trying to do specifically". Perhaps a more concrete question?

Comment: Well, data-wise that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm just not doing it with Employee and Product tables. I'm just pre-empting someone questioning why I'd move the ProductRefID to the Employee table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
alter table Employee add ProductRefID INT


update e
set ProductRefID = p.ProductRefID
from Employee e
join 
Product p
on e.ProductID = p.id
```

Comment: That's certainly what I'd do.